# How is a relation defined on ordered sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am reading that $(\mathbb{Z}, \leq )$ is a total ordered set. I understand how it satisfies reflexivity, antisymmetry, transitivity.

But it says that because for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$.

So if $a \sim b \iff a \leq b$, doesn't that mean if I choose $a = 2$ and $b = 1$, then it is not true that every $a,b,$ is either $a \leq b$?

**EDIT**: I thought that when we define relation on $(\mathbb{Z}, \leq )$, we define it as $$a \sim b \iff a \leq b$$ and not $$a \sim b \iff a \leq b \;\text{ or } \;b \leq a$$

Comment: In the case of $a=2$ and $b=1$, you do have "either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$"; you have $b \leq a$.

Comment: But the relation is $a \sim b$ is $a\leq b$, not $b \leq a.$ So the union statement cannot be considered.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "is either $a \leq b$"?

Comment: I did not, that's what I read from the proof.

Comment: A totally ordered set $S$ has the property that $\forall a,b \in S$, either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$; further, if $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$, then $a=b$. In your case, this satisfies the property because $b \leq a$, $a \not\leq b$.

Comment: I see, actually from this we see that our set cannot be partially ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pick $a=2$ and $b=1$, then it may not be true that $a\le b$, but it is that $b\le a$, and for it to be total ordered it is required that either $a\le b$ or $b\leq a$, not both (except in $a=b$ situation).

As far as relation being $a\leq b$ and not $b\leq a $, it is important to note that $a$ and $b$ are just placeholders and can be interchanged. The relation itself can be thought of as just $\leq$.

Edit: noticed after posting that this was already stated in the comments.

Comment: But that's not the relation?

Comment: No, i mean to say the relation is $a \leq b$ for distinct $a,b$. Isn't it?

Comment: @sidht: No. The relation applies to any a and b from the set (that makes it total ordered), however it can be either a≤b or b≤a (for some distinct a and b).

Comment: So the underlying relation is what I wrote in my edit?

Comment: @sidht: except for the 'and', that would mean that for every a and b both a≤b and b≤a is true, which would mean a=b, thus making it a single-element set. You should replace 'and' with 'or'. It is a non-exclusive 'or' though. :)

Comment: that "and" was a typo. Is that relation supposed to be "natural"? Because it wasn't obvious to me that the proof was using that relation instead of the one I was thinking. (@ is not working??)

Comment: @sidht I'm not sure what do you mean by 'natural', but this is what is meant by relation (as far as I know always). The difference is when a and b are taken to be specific, then it is not the same, but in this example they serve as placeholders. (e.g. it is not 2≤1 but 1≤2, you can replace ≤ with ~ if you like, but it is a≤b or b≤a in general)

Comment: actually from this question, we see that our set cannot be partially ordered. Maybe this will answered why I was confused in the first place.

Comment: it can be partially ordered, and it is partially ordered. Total order requires the set to be partially ordered in the first place ('total order' means partial order plus 'for every a and b in the set, either a~b or b~a').

Comment: I meant to say that if we define $a \sim b$ as just $a \leq b$ (without $b \leq a$)